# How can I apply an event to a simple link element in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, events, event-handling

I have an `<asp:Image>` element and a text caption, surrounded by an `<a>` element. I need the link to run a method when clicked, changing the ImageUrl property of another `<asp:Image>` element.

I'm a total noob with ASP.NET (Clearly.)
Can anyone explain this process to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is changing the image the *only* thing you're doing?  If so, you should probably keep this all in javascript, or least try to use javascript first and only postback if javascript is disabled.  Server events are bad for performance.

Comment: This is probably the best answer, and it is definitely a very simple task that Javascript can handle in a heartbeat. But I'm not so great with Javascript or ASP.NET web forms. Can you give me a code example, showing what elements to use and how to link them to the Javascript?

Comment: It's as simple as `document.getElementById('myimageID').src="newSource.jpg";`

Comment: yes, good point. if it's simply a client-side change, javascript will do it.

Answer (score 3):

I think the ImageButton control will do it for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.aspx

It fires a postback, giving you all the events you expect.

Comment: That would be perfect, as long as it doesn't look retarded. I don't want any vusual "button" movements or animations - like when the button is depressed.

Comment: No, it doesn't behave visually like an HTML button. Just an image.

Answer (score 2):

An imagebutton will be your best bet.  It is basically a button but the look of simply an image.  There is no depressing or any movement with this control.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Method on the Server?

Then you need to use the ASP.NET [Link Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tw3zz4t%28VS.80%29.aspx).  You can hook up to the OnClick event on the Link Control.

Comment: I can't find the Link control anywhere in my toolbox. It is not a mobile web page. Is the Link control not available for reguar ASP.NET web forms?